# How to constantly poll the server without causing my computer to crash

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing the front-end of a multiplayer Tic Tac Toe game and I want to constantly poll the server for the Tic Tac Toe board. The problem is that doing so causes my CPU usage to spike significantly high. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
const grabBoard = (async () => {
     if (boardId != null) {
       if (boardData == null) {
         setIsLoaded(false);
       }
       setBoardData(await getBoard(boardId));
     }
   })
   grabBoard()
 }, )
```

Comment: the computer crash because you use unlimited recusion. call stack has a limit. idk what js limits commonly is. but probably around 2mb.